# Failed to create table after install hive-0.7.1 using MySQL as the metastore

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I installed hive-0.7.1 using MySQL 5.5 as the metastore. When I tried to create a simple table, it failed. I got exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiveone`.`tbls`, CONSTRAINT `TBLS_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`SD_ID`) REFERENCES `SDS` (`SD_ID`))
```

Please help to advice how I should proceed.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object     "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable@4d092447" using statement "INSERT INTO `TBLS` (`TBL_ID`,`LAST_ACCESS_TIME`,`TBL_TYPE`,`CREATE_TIME`,`OWNER`,`SD_ID`,`RETENTION`,`VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT`,`TBL_NAME`,`DB_ID`,`VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" failed : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiveone`.`tbls`, CONSTRAINT `TBLS_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`SD_ID`) REFERENCES `SDS` (`SD_ID`))
NestedThrowables:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiveone`.`tbls`, CONSTRAINT `TBLS_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`SD_ID`) REFERENCES `SDS` (`SD_ID`))
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

hive-site.xml settings as below:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiveone?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hadoop</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>pwd</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Tables in MySQL are listed below:

SDS table is empty.

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_hiveone |
+-------------------+
| BUCKETING_COLS |
| COLUMNS |
| DATABASE_PARAMS |
| PARTITION_KEYS |
| SDS |
| SD_PARAMS |
| SEQUENCE_TABLE |
| SERDES |
| SERDE_PARAMS |
| SORT_COLS |
| TABLE_PARAMS |
| TBLS |
| dbs |
+-------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The question is what SDS data does Hive expect?

Answer (score 1):

hive-0.7.1 doesn't support MySQL 5.5. End of the story.